# Is it possible to have my server transparently forward requests on a specific port to a website?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

There is a website that I can only access from a few whitelisted IP addresses. Let's call it xyz.com. Further, xyz.com only allows connections over https.

I also have a Debian 8.10 server with a static IP address that is one of the whitelisted IPs, and I have a DNS name set up for it. Let's say it's myserver.biz.

What I would like to do is connect to myserver.biz on a particular part (let's say 12345) and have it forward the request to xyz.com such that it will actually get that website and won't have any SSL issues that I can't create exceptions for.

My first attempt was to use `iptables` on my server to transparently forward all incoming requests on port 12345 to the IP address of xyz.com's server on port 443. i.e.:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to <xyz.com's server IP>:443
iptables -t nat -a POSTROUTING -d <xyz.com's server IP> -j MASQUERADE
```

This *almost* worked, but not quite. If I pointed my browser to myserver.biz:12345, it wouldn't work because xyz.com is on shared hosting and the server wouldn't process my request as though I was connecting to xyz.com.

However, if I edited my computer's hosts file such that xyz.com resolved to my server's static IP address, and then pointed my browser to xyz.com:12345, it *would* work. So it gets me part of the way there, but it only works on systems where I can access the hosts file, and I need it to work on systems where I can't do that (e.g. iOS devices).

So in summary, I need:

- requests to myserver.biz:12345 to be forwarded to xyz.com:443
- the forwarded request's hostname to specify xyz.com so that it will be resolved correctly by xyz'com's server
- and the forwarded request's source IP address be my whitelisted server's IP address

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

#### Update:

I've been working on using `nginx` to do this, and while I've managed to get my server to forward to a variety of different websites, I can't get it to work with the one I need! It consistently produces a "502: Bad Gateway". I'm not sure what's going wrong.

#### Update #2:

I've managed to get `nginx` mostly working. The trick was to update it to the latest stable version and include `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` in my server definition. However, now there's an issue where some of the images on xyz.com are not loading with a 403 status.

It appears the 403 is due to the server trying to prevent hotlinking. Not sure how to resolve that at this juncture...

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a *reverse proxy server*. One such example is nginx.

Comment: I've been trying to set up nginx for the last hour and haven't been able to get it working as described in my question. If you can offer and advice or help I would certainly appreciate it.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Don't worry, I'm aware of that. I'm planning on doing something like restricting access to ngnix by IP address or minimally requiring a secure password. Unfortunately I cannot use a VPN for this, as some of the devices I'm connecting from are already using a VPN, and the VPN's IP address is specifically *not* whitelisted by the site I'm trying to connect to.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I do not control the VPN, as it's a VPN service for anonymizing web traffic. But yes, the idea is that the systems utilizing that VPN could connect to my server, which would redirect the traffic  to the target website so that it's coming from a whitelisted IP.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Several of the devices that use my VPN and need to connect to this site are iOS device. Do you know if it's possible to set that up on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to get this working using a reverse proxy, specifically `nginx`. After doing some experimenting, I found that what I needed to do was set it up with an SSL certificate and then use its `proxy_pass` feature to forward to my desired website. The simplest version of my configuration (with the SSL parts excluded) was:

```
server {
    listen 12345;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    location /some_path/ {
        proxy_pass https://example.com/;
        proxy_set_header Referer "https://example.com";
    }
}
```

I set up a self-signed certificate using the first half of [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins). It was necessary to include `proxy_ssl_server_name on;` as without doing so `nginx` would fail with a `502: Bad Gateway` error.

Comment: Cool, now would be a good time to secure it!

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I'm wondering which security mechanism I should use. I could use basic auth, but that has the downside of having to enter the username and password every time I use the proxy. (iOS doesn't have an option for remembering those passwords!) Given that the website I'm proxying already requires a login and password, do you think it would be sufficient to set the `location` in the nginx server configuration to a long string of random characters?

Comment: I would think basic auth or IP range. I know the user/pass sucks, but sadly even that doesn't always deter attempts. Most VPN services have you isolated from other VPN client accounts, I would try it with IP, and keep an eye on the logs.